# Maven dependency plugin does not resolve manually specified dependencies for a plugin

Tags: java, maven

I have encountered a problem with `maven-dependency-plugin` (Maven version `3.2.3`, `maven-dependency-plugin` version `2.10`). I am trying to introduce plugin dependencies. I created a simple project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sze</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvn-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have chosen the maven-antrun-plugin version 1.2, cause this plugin and its dependencies were mentioned in the [Maven Official Guide to Configuring Plug-ins](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_dependencies_Tag). Then I run a command to resolve it's dependencies:

```
mvn dependency:resolve-plugins
```

The output:

```
[INFO] Plugin Resolved: maven-antrun-plugin-1.2.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-plugin-api-2.0.1.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-project-2.0.1.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: ant-launcher-1.6.5.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: ant-1.6.5.jar
```

Indeed, I have `ant` and `ant-launcher` version `1.6.5`. Now I want to change the version of these dependencies and change my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sze</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvn-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-launcher</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But when I run again `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins`, the version of the dependencies that belong to the `maven-antrun-plugin` is still `1.6.5`:

```
[INFO] Plugin Resolved: maven-antrun-plugin-1.2.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-plugin-api-2.0.1.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-project-2.0.1.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: ant-launcher-1.6.5.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: ant-1.6.5.jar
```

How else can I check that the version of these dependencies is changed?

Comment: How did you check this? Could you show some output as well, please?

Comment: I have just added some changes to my initial question.

Comment: Why do you need that? why do you use a [so old version of this plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-antrun-plugin%22) (Note that v1.3 has exactly the dep you want)?

Comment: I am just following the [manual](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_dependencies_Tag). It uses maven-antrun-plugin version 1.2.

Comment: You seemed to misunderstand the different between what the plugin has as dependencies and what is on the classpath during the runtime of the plugins. Have you checked `mvn -X clean package` and searched for the appropriate entries...Furthermore you should read the output `Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-plugin-api-2.0.1.jar` means the dependency of the plugin and not what on the classpath is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, the `resolve-plugins` goal will **not** resolve custom plugin dependencies. If you want to see which plugins are actually used, you will have to run Maven in debug mode:

```
mvn -X antrun:run
```

This will show you the dependencies that are added to the classpath:

```
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.2:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.1:runtime
[DEBUG]    org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.1:runtime
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.0.5:compile
[DEBUG]          classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]    ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.6.5:runtime
[DEBUG]    ant:ant:jar:1.6.5:compile
```

Notice that the group ID of the original dependencies is **not** `org.apache.ant` but just `ant`. This will cause Maven to include both `ant:ant:1.6.5` and `org.apache.ant:ant:1.7.1`. However, custom dependencies will come first on the classpath, so you will be able to use the newer ant version.

Comment: Why the `maven-dependency-plugin` doesn't show two dependencies for a `maven-antrun-plugin`? I have added two dependencies (so I will have two `ant` artifacts and two `ant-launcher` artifacts, that differ by their groupId). They must have been added to the list of the plugin's dependencies. Why the command `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins` doesn't resolve them?

Comment: I have just changed the plugin. I have chosen `tomcat7-maven-plugin` version `2.2`. It uses artifact `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj` version `4.2.2`. I want it to use version `4.4.2`. So I change the `pom.xml` as described above. But the dependency plugin still shows that a resolved dependency has `4.2.2` version.

Comment: The `resolve-plugins` goal does not resolve custom dependencies. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand. Just to launch in debug (`-X`) mode. Custom dependencies are placed at the beginning of the classpath as java stops searching for a class in the classpath search list after first `.class` file found. The scope of the dependencies is marked as `runtime` because these artifacts don't participate during the compilation of the plugin, they are added to already deployed one. So I expect to have a default `runtime` scope in the effective pom. But why it is still `compile` scope when I execute `mvn help:effective-pom`? But ok, it is outside of the original topic. Thx