# Override maven plugins dependecy

Tags: java, maven

I have to override dependency in maven plugin: `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:maven-plugin:3.9.1` and in this plugin I have dependency `commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0` and I have to override version to ver `1.9.4` and I added dependencies tag with new version of commons-utils but it still doesn't override. When I run `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins` I still see old version

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

[INFO]    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:maven-plugin:3.3:runtime
[INFO]       commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0
```

As we can see in this log common beanutils is nessesery

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:resolve-plugins (default-cli) @ everything ---
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.pom (357 B at 645 B/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar (189 kB at 586 kB/s)
```

And I found where this beanutils is used

```
org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:2.3
   commons-validator:commons-validator:1.3.1
      commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.7.0
```

maven dependency tree doesn't have any beanutils
and plugins which I'm using are:

- org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2-maven-plugin.2.3.1
- org.apache.maven.plugin
- org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-maven-plugin
- org.jacoco.jacoco-maven-plugin.0.8.7

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: could you provide a minimum pom.xml ?

Comment: @Vokail I added plugin from pom.xml

Comment: @MateuszSobczak Are you sure `maven-site-plugin` has `commons-beanutils` dependence?? I could not find it in pom.xml

Comment: here is the relevant QA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938726/maven-dependency-plugin-does-not-resolve-manually-specified-dependencies-for-a-p

tl.dr. dependencies:resolve-plugins does not show manually specified dependencies, but if  you run `mvn site -X` the correct version will show up in the logs

Comment: First question: Why do you need to override a dependency of a plugin?

Comment: Because of security policy

Comment: A CVE or alike describes a scenario where an issue could be a problem. But I doubt that this scenario will apply for a Maven plugin. Furthermore I would really check if the plugin really has the dependency to commons-beantutils..as far as I know the code of the maven-site-plugin there is no use of such kind...

Comment: From logs I can see that maven always download this lib in ver 1.7.0, and I really don't know from where

Comment: @MateuszSobczak Can you provide your pom.xml ?

Comment: @nhatnq I added what I could

Answer (score 0):

You can double check your dependencies one by one to find more dependencies which are using `maven-reporting-impl:2.3`. Somehow I think what could be reason for that is `jaxb2-maven-plugin.2.3.1`. The `maven-checkstyle-plugin` is defined in the pom of the plugin. It has a dependence to `maven-reporting-impl:2.3`

> jaxb2-maven-plugin

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <!-- Apache plugins in alphabetical order -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
      <skip>true</skip>
      <configLocation>config/maven_checks.xml</configLocation>
      <headerLocation>config/maven-header.txt</headerLocation>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

> maven-checkstyle-plugin

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.reporting</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-reporting-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

You are not possible to override as it comes from another project